# XNA sorting score from array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, xna

I want to create a highscore board for my game.
the score board contain the top 5 scores in the text file

the text file are something like this:

```
alpha, 3500
beta, 3600
gamma, 2200
delta, 3400
epsilon, 2000
```

and this is my codes :

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct HighScoreData
    {
        public string[] PlayerName;
        public int[] Score; 

        public int Count;

        public HighScoreData(int count)
        {
            PlayerName = new string[count];
            Score = new int[count];

            Count = count;
        }

    }

    static HighScoreData highScores;
```

this codes for reading data from text file and already add sorting in it:
            try
            {

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscore.txt"))
            {

                string line;
                int i = 0;
                //file = new StreamReader(filePath);

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

                {

                    string[] parts = line.Split(',');                       
                    highScores.PlayerName[i] = parts[0].Trim();
                    highScores.Score[i] = Int32.Parse(parts[1].Trim());                       
                    i++;
                    Array.Sort(highScores.Score);
                }


            }


        }
```

this is how I draw it :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, i + 1 + ". " + highScores.PlayerName[i].ToString()
           , new Vector2(200, 150 + 50 * (i)), Color.Red);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, highScores.Score[i].ToString(),
                new Vector2(550, 150 + 50 * (i)), Color.Red);
        }
```

the problem is when I run the game, it only sorting the scores and not the player name. and also, the first and secod scores in text file are identified as "0". it displayed like this :

```
   alpha 0
   beta 0
   gamma 2000
   delta 2200
   epsilon 3400
```

what must I do, so the program can sorting all the data in the text file, not only the score...?

Answer (score 0):

Make a struct named PlayerScore

```
struct PlayerScore 
{
    public string Player;
    public int Score;
    public int DataYouWant;

    public static int Compare(PlayerScore A, PlayerScore B)
    {
        return A.Score - B.Score;
    }
}
```

and then to Sort call only one time, (outside the while) to the sort method this way:

```
Array.Sort<PlayerScore>( yourArray, PlayerScore.Compare );
```

Do you really need to have more than HighScoreData instance? I think that no.. so you store your highscores this way:

```
static PlayerScore[] highScores = new PlayerScore[MaxHighScorePlayers];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option without comparers using LINQ based on Blau's sample:

```
struct PlayerScore
{
    public string Player;
    public int Score;
    public int DataYouWant;
}
```

then a sample of populating the list and sorting it:

```
        List<PlayerScore> scores = new List<PlayerScore>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            scores.Add(new PlayerScore()
            {
                Player = "Player" + i,
                Score = rand.Next(1,1000)
            });
        }
        scores = (from s in scores orderby s.Score descending select s).ToList();
        foreach (var score in scores)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Player: {0}, Score: {1}", score.Player, score.Score);
        }
```